# jQuery definitions function not selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just came across an error after upgrading to jquery 3.1.1

The admin can click an edit user button which launches a modal and propagates the input fields with fetched user data from the database. The input fields selectors are in the first function.

`data.email.val(result.email);` or rather `users.add_edit_data.email.val(result.email)` doesn't change the value of the field with id email. No console errors are present. The result is being correctly fetched, and I can log it via `console.log(result.email)`. Directly assigning the value via `$('#email').val(result.email);` works as expected. I'm not sure what happened as this code was working prior to upgrading and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Not really sure how to debug this from here on.

```
/**
 * Helps match input fields with values and general assignments
 */
users.add_edit_data = {
    username: $('#username'),
    email: $('#email'),
    first_name: $('#first_name'),
    last_name: $('#last_name'),
    address: $('#address'),
    phone: $('#phone'),
    password: $('#password'),
    fb_id: $('#fb_id'),
    country: $('#country'),
    city: $('#city'),
    confirm_password: $('#confirm_password'),
    button: $('#btn-add-user')
};

/**
 * Gets user details and propogates it in the input fields
 * 
 * @param {int} user_id
 */
users.edit_user = function (user_id) {
    $('#user-id').val(user_id);
    var modal = $('#modal-add-edit-user');
    var data = users.add_edit_data;
    var modal_title = modal.find('.modal-title');
    var modal_body = modal.find('.m-body');
    var ajax_loading = modal.find('.ajax-loading');
    //data.button.attr('onclick', 'users.update_user();');
    neou_cms.remove_error_messages();
    modal.modal('show');
    modal_title.text($_lang.processing_loading);
    modal_body.hide();
    ajax_loading.show();
    console.log(users.add_edit_data.username);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_path + 'access_control/get_user_details',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            user_id: user_id
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status === 'error') {
                toastr.error(result.msg);
                modal.modal('hide');
            } else {
                data.email.val(result.email);
                data.username.val(result.username);
                data.first_name.val(result.first_name);
                data.last_name.val(result.last_name);
                data.address.val(result.address);
                data.phone.val(result.phone);
                data.fb_id.val(result.fb_id);
                data.country.val(result.country);
                data.city.val(result.city);
                data.password.attr('placeholder', $_lang.validation_leave_blank);
                data.confirm_password.attr('placeholder', $_lang.validation_leave_blank);
                data.button.text($_lang.actions_update);
                modal_title.text(result.username);
            }
            ajax_loading.hide();
            modal_body.show();
        }
    });
};
```

**In dev tools typing `users.add_edit_data.username.val('12312');` yields `r.fn.init {}` and I'm 100% sure input with id username exists and is unique. I have an old working copy of the site with an older jquery version and typing the same as above yields `r.fn.init [input#username.form-control]` and changes the value.**

EDIT: the script was loaded in the wrong area (top instead of bottom). voted to close as I cannot delete.

Comment: use `stmt.defs.username.val('hello world');`?

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to access `stmt.defs.username.val` - you forgot the `defs`:

```js
var stmt = {};

stmt.defs = {
  username: $('#hw')
};

stmt.defs.username.val('hello world');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input type="input" id="hw" name="hw">
```

Comment: updated my question as my example was incorrect. i apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Your object `stmt` is as follows:

```
stmt = {
    defs: {
        username: $('#hw')
    }
}
```

So you can change the value of username property by using:
`stmt.defs.username = 'Hello world';`

if you want to update the value of your `input` element then use `$('#hw').val('Hello World')`

Comment: updated my question as my example was incorrect. i apologize for the inconvenience.